# How to move gtk window on a specific position on the screen under wayland?

Tags: c, gtk3, ubuntu-22.04, wayland, gdk

I'm trying to move the gtk window to a certain position on the screen under wayland. Here is the demo script, but it's not working. What should be changed to make it work, Can someone check this please? -

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <gdk/gdkwayland.h>
#include <wayland-client.h>
//gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o example-0 example-0.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0` -l wayland-client

struct wl_compositor *compositor;
struct wl_shell *shell;
struct wl_shm *shm;
void registry_global_handler
(
    void *data,
    struct wl_registry *registry,
    uint32_t name,
    const char *interface,
    uint32_t version
) {
    if (strcmp(interface, "wl_compositor") == 0) {
        compositor = wl_registry_bind(registry, name,
            &wl_compositor_interface, 3);
    } else if (strcmp(interface, "wl_shm") == 0) {
        shm = wl_registry_bind(registry, name,
            &wl_shm_interface, 1);
    } else if (strcmp(interface, "wl_shell") == 0) {
        shell = wl_registry_bind(registry, name,
            &wl_shell_interface, 1);
    }
}

void registry_global_remove_handler
(
    void *data,
    struct wl_registry *registry,
    uint32_t name
) {}

const struct wl_registry_listener registry_listener = {
    .global = registry_global_handler,
    .global_remove = registry_global_remove_handler
};



int move_Window (GtkWidget *widget)
{
    GdkDisplay *gdk_display = gdk_display_get_default ();
   if (GDK_IS_WAYLAND_DISPLAY (gdk_display))
    {
        struct wl_display *display = gdk_wayland_display_get_wl_display (gdk_display);
       // display  = gdk_wayland_display_get_wl_display (gdk_window_get_display (widget));
        if (display) {
            printf("wayland\n");
            struct wl_registry *registry = wl_display_get_registry(display);
            wl_registry_add_listener(registry, &registry_listener, NULL);

            // wait for the "initial" set of globals to appear
            wl_display_roundtrip(display);

            struct wl_surface *surface = wl_compositor_create_surface(compositor);

            GdkWindow *w = gtk_widget_get_window (GTK_WIDGET(widget));
            struct wl_surface *w_surface = gdk_wayland_window_get_wl_surface (w);
            struct wl_shell_surface *shell_surface = wl_shell_get_shell_surface(shell, surface);
            wl_shell_surface_set_toplevel(shell_surface);

            wl_shell_surface_set_transient(shell_surface, surface, 300, 200, 0);
            while (1) {
                   //wl_display_dispatch(display);
           }
        }
    }
    if (GDK_IS_X11_DISPLAY(gdk_display)){
        printf("x11\n");
    }
}


static void
print_hello (GtkWidget *widget,
             gpointer   data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void
activate (GtkApplication *app,
          gpointer        user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;
  GtkWidget *button_box;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button_box = gtk_button_box_new (GTK_ORIENTATION_HORIZONTAL);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), button_box);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_widget_destroy), window);
  gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (button_box), button);

  gtk_widget_show_all (window);
       move_Window(window);
}

int
main (int    argc,
      char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Is it possible to do it via the new protocol? How can it be done if possible?

i want to move gtkwindow under waylan,